# Kibana Timelion plugin how to specify a field in the elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

I'm trying to use [Timelion](https://github.com/elastic/timelion) plugin for kibana.

I have a dataset in the elasticsearch, the structure may be like this:

```
{
    "_index": "metrics-2016-03",
    "_type": "gauge",
    "_id": "AVM2O7gbLYPaOnNTBgG0",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "name": "kafka.network.RequestChannel.ResponseQueueSize",
        "@timestamp": "2016-03-02T07:29:56.000+0000",
        "value": 4,
        "host": "localhost"
    }
}
```

I want to show the `"value"` field as the y axis and `"@timestamp"` as the x aixs, how should I do?

I tried the `.es()` function, but this function seems to set the count as the default value, not the "value" field in the datasource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timelion uses pre-defined time intervals for its time plots.
In order to plot the "value" as function of time you can set the granularity to 'Auto' and use this string:

```
 .es(metric='max:value')
```

You can also set the granularity to the minimum possible and add `.fit(carry)` to the above string in order to fill null values, in that case you can replace `max` with `min` or `avg`, it will produce the same plot (`sum` won't work here).

Answer (score 2):

```
.es(metric='sum:value')
```

Try above, it should work fine, make sure you configured **timeline.json**

Comment: how can I  configure timeline.json to get the  required  result ?