# Using Timelion in ElasticSearch/Kibana 5.0

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

I'm trying to visualize a timeseries in Timelion. I have a few hundred datapoints in elasticsearch with this sort of format - I've manually removed some fields which I never meant to use in the timeseries plot.

```
        "_index": "foo-2016-11-06",
        "_type": "bar",
        "_id": "7239171989271733678",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "timestamp": "2016-11-06T15:27:37.123581+00:00",
           "rank": 2,
        }
```

What I want is to quite simply plot the change in rank over time. I found this post [Kibana Timelion plugin how to specify a field in the elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762103/kibana-timelion-plugin-how-to-specify-a-field-in-the-elastic-search) which seems to describe the same thing and I understand I should be able to just do .es(metric='sum:rank').

My problem is that no matter how I define my timelion query (even just calling .es(*)), I end up just getting a horizontal line where y=0.

[timelion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JysHN.png)

Things I've tried so far:

- Changed timefield in timelion.json from @timefield to just timefield
- Extending the timeseries window (even into the future)
- Set default_index to _all in timelion.json
- Queried specific indices that I know contain data

All of them give me the same outcome which you can see in the attached picture. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Set the *timelion.json* as above:

```
{
        "quandl": {
            "key": ""
        },
        "es": {
            "timefield": "timestamp",
            "default_index": "_all",
            "allow_url_parameter": false
        },
        "graphite": {
            "url": "https://www.hostedgraphite.com/UID/ACCESS_KEY/graphite"
        },
        "default_interval": "1h",
        "max_buckets": 2000
}
```

set the granularity to 'Auto' and use the above Timelion query:`.es(index='foo-2016-11-06', metric='max:rank')`.